# Neo4j Cypher query deleting a node and all children nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is part of my Neo4j code in Cypher:

```
CREATE 
(search{id : '0', title : 'Begin Search'}),
(telephone { id : '2' , title : 'Telephone' }),
(tablet { id : '1' , title : 'Tablet' }),
(printer { id : '3' , title : 'Printer' }),
(scanner { id : '4' , title : 'Scanner' }),
(laptop { id : '5' , title : 'Laptop' }),
(pc { id : '6' , title : 'Personal Computer' }),
(monitor { id : '7' , title : 'Monitor' }),

(galaxykids7wifi { id : '100' , model : ' Galaxy Tab 3 Kids 7.0 wi-fi', brand : 'Samsung', processor : 'Dual-Core Processor', network : 'Android Jelly Bean 4.1', memory : '8 Gb' , screen : '7 inches ', wieght : '302 g', dimensions : '111.1*188*9.9 mm' , battery : '4000 mAh', wifi : '802.11', wifi_speed : '2.4 + 5 GHz', wifi_type : 'a/b/g/n', ram : '1 Gb', kamera : '3 Mpix' }),
(galaxytab310wifi3g { id : '101' , model : ' Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 wi-fi + 3 G', brand : 'Samsung', processor : 'Dual-Core Intel Atom Processor', network : 'Android 2.2', memory : '16 Gb', memory1 : '32 Gb' , screen : '10.1 inches ', wieght : '512 g', dimensions : '176.1*243,1*7.45 mm' , battery : '6800 mAh', wifi : '802.11', wifi_speed : '2.4 + 5 GHz', wifi_type : 'a/b/g/n', ram : '1 Gb', kamera : '3 Mpix' }),
(galaxytab310wifi { id : '102' , model : ' Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 wi-fi', brand : 'Samsung', processor : 'Dual-Core Intel Atom Processor', network : 'Android 2.2', memory : '16 Gb',memory1 : '32 Gb' , screen : '10.1 inches ', wieght : '510 g', dimensions : '176.1*243,1*7.45 mm' , battery : '6800 mAh', wifi : '802.11', wifi_speed : '2.4 + 5 GHz', wifi_type : 'a/b/g/n', ram : '1 Gb', kamera : '3 Mpix' }), 
(galaxytab38wifi3g { id : '103' , model : ' Galaxy Tab 3 8.0 wi-fi + 3 G', brand : 'Samsung', processor : 'Dual-Core Processor', network : 'Android JB 4.2.2', memory : '16 Gb', memory1 : '32 Gb' , screen : '8 inches ', wieght : '316 g', dimensions : '123.8*209.8*7.4 mm' , battery : '4450 mAh', wifi : '802.11', wifi_speed : '2.4 + 5 GHz', wifi_type : 'a/b/g/n', ram : '1.5 Gb', kamera : '5 Mpix'}),
(galaxytab38wifi { id : '104' , model : ' Galaxy Tab 3 8.0 wi-fi', brand : 'Samsung', processor : 'Dual-Core Processor', network : 'Android JB 4.2.2', memory : '16 Gb', memory1 : '32 Gb' , screen : '8 inches ', wieght : '314 g', dimensions : '204.8*123.8*7.4 mm' , battery : '4450 mAh', wifi : '802.11', wifi_speed : '2.4 + 5 GHz', wifi_type : 'a/b/g/n', ram : '1.5 Gb', kamera : '5 Mpix'}),

(search)<-[:TYPE]-(tablet),
(search)<-[:TYPE]-(telephone),
(search)<-[:TYPE]-(printer),
(search)<-[:TYPE]-(scanner),
(search)<-[:TYPE]-(laptop),
(search)<-[:TYPE]-(pc),
(search)<-[:TYPE]-(monitor),

(tablet)<-[:TYPE]-(galaxykids7wifi),
(tablet)<-[:TYPE] -(galaxytab310wifi3g),
(tablet)<-[:TYPE]-(galaxytab310wifi),
(tablet)<-[:TYPE]-(galaxytab38wifi3g),
(tablet)<-[:TYPE]-(galaxytab38wifi)
```

I'm trying to delete lets say node 1 with all children nodes attached to it (in this case the products) and relationships shared between them. I've tried numerous solutions people say work over various web pages, but i keep on getting this

```
'STATEMENT_EXECUTION_ERROR' : 'Node with id 1'
```

I'm guessing the problem is that the query can't read where node with `id : 1` is, but that makes no sense. Please help me if possible.

Queries like this one don't work:

```
start n=node(1) 
match n-[*]-x 
WITH x 
MATCH x-[r]-() delete x,r
```

**EDIT**

The two answers below don't work either. I'm running Neo4j 2.0.0 - M06

1)

```
MATCH (n {id:'1'})<-[r]-x-[ss*0..]-y
WHERE NOT r IN ss  
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[t]->()
FOREACH (s IN ss | DELETE s)
DELETE r,y,t,n

Error: Invalid input 'P' : expected 'r/R'
   "OPTIONAL MATCH n-[t]->()"
     ^
```

2)

```
match (n {id : '1'})
optional match n-[r]-x
delete r,x

Invalid input 'o': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship patter, .....
"optional match n-[r]-x"
 ^
```

Comment: I've reformatted your question to make it readable. See here for how to do that yourself next time: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You are using a development (unfinished) version of Neo4j. Please use the released Neo4j 2.0 GA and if you still have problems you can post back.

Answer (score 5):

When you refer to node(1) you are not referring to a node which has an id property with value 1, rather, you are asking for a node with internal id 1 (internally maintained by Neo4j, you have no control over assigning this value). So this is probably the reason it cannot locate node with id 1.

If you're on 2.0, then something like this would work(not tested):

```
match (n {id : '1'})
optional match n-[r]-x
delete r,x
```

Answer (score 3):

Luanne already answered the error and therefore the question (please mark his answer as accepted if the error goes away), but if you want to delete everything attached to your graph through `(tablet)` you also need a better pattern. Something like this should work on your data sample

```
MATCH (n {id:'1'})<-[r]-x-[ss*0..]-y
WHERE NOT r IN ss  //I expected relationship uniqueness to ensure that 'r' is not traversed twice, but it didn't so I added an explicit check
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[t]->()
FOREACH (s IN ss | DELETE s)
DELETE r,y,t,n
```

However, if your graph is not strictly a tree and the sub graph is attached somewhere else, say a user `[:OWNS]` both a galaxytab38wifi and some printer, then user, all printers and everything connected to them will also be deleted. So you'll probably want to limit the pattern further or be careful about the order of your data.